# Two interpretations of “ if not more” in this sentence

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, grammar, phrase-meaning

I’m Japanese and learning English.
I have a question about the meaning of “**if not more**” in the below sentence.

*Many people who follow this diet end up eating just as many calories,* **if not more** *, because they constantly feel hungry.*

According to my text, this means “... end up eating just as many calories as before they begin it, **or even more calories than before they begin it.**”

However, I interpreted as “... end up eating just as many calories as before they begin it, **not to say more calories than before they begin it.**”

Which of the two is correct? And why?

Answer (score 1):

The placement of **if not more** in the sentence might be a little misleading. It actually goes with **just as many**, but it can be placed before or after **calories**.

> ...just as many, if not more, calories.

They eat just as many calories [as they would have eaten while not on this diet] and *perhaps* even more calories [than they would have eaten while not on this diet], because the diet makes them feel hungry.

Comment: It's worth noting that the OP's interpretation was also *not* correct in this case.  That interpretation ("not to say more") would be correct if the phrase were "not more", but with an "if" ("if not more") the meaning changes to be "it may be more, but *if* it's not more, then it's just as many"

Answer (score 0):

Literally, *than X, if not more* is a short way of saying *or possibly even more than that same X*.

In your example the "than X" is understood.

*If not more* is used if someone's expectations are significantly below what happens in reality.

> Many people who follow this diet end up eating just as many calories [than someone], if not more than that same someone, because they constantly feel hungry.

Answer (score 0):

"I would like to have a pay raise of $500, if not more, for next month."

This means I expect at least $500 but I don't mind if it is more than $500.

Comment: Does this work in the original example "Most people will end up eating as many calories, if not more.  Does this mean "Most people will expect to eat at least the same amount, but don't mind if it is more"?